# How can I use "setTitle" at API level 17

Tags: java, android, android-studio

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
toolbar.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
```

Hello. 
I want to use my application at API level 17. But Android Studio says that the API level for "setTitle" should be 26. How can I solve this at API level 17?

Edit: I'm trying to get it done: "Android Lisview OnItemClick Example."

Comment: Are you setting the toolbar as the action bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're setting the toolbar as the action bar (using `setSupportActionBar(toolbar)`), then you can set the title with:

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar.setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
```